# Flutter/Dart: Why is 'await' not waiting in my async recursive function?

Tags: flutter, dart, recursion, async-await

```dart
if (isDrumsSelected) {
    final List<AudioPlayer> drumBeatsAudioPlayersList = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBars; i++) {
        drumBeatsAudioPlayersList.add(AudioPlayer());
        await drumBeatsAudioPlayersList[i].setAsset('assets/drum_beats/$drumBeatsFolderSelected/${bpmSliderValue.toInt()}BPM.mp3');
    }

    int n = 0;
    
    Future<void> playNextPlayer(int index) async {
      
        if (index < numberOfBars) {
        
            drumBeatsAudioPlayersList[index].play();
        
            drumBeatsAudioPlayersList[index].positionStream.listen((position) async {
            
                final duration = drumBeatsAudioPlayersList[index].duration;
          
                if (duration != null) {
                    final remaining = duration - position;
                    const timeThreshold = Duration(milliseconds: 110);

                    if (remaining <= timeThreshold) {
                        if (index + 1 < numberOfBars) {
                            drumBeatsAudioPlayersList[index + 1].play();
                            await playNextPlayer(index + 1); // Call recursively for the next player
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    await playNextPlayer(n); // Start the sequence

    /// Stop the recording(& music) and...
    await ourSoundRecorder.stop();

    /// ...play the recording.
    await recordingPlayer.setFilePath(filePath);
    await recordingPlayer.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
    await recordingPlayer.play();
}
```

I'm calling 'playNextPlayer' method recursively and expecting that when and only when all the players have finished playing, should `await ourSoundRecorder.stop();` execute.

But it's executing just after the first player of 'drumBeatsAudioPlayerList' has started playing & not waiting for all the players to finish playing.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code. It's unreadable.

Comment: @Dai apologies for that. I've formated the code. Please, check it now.

Comment: @Dai may you please check it now. It's just an if {}, with a for{} loop and a 'playNextPlayer(index)' method called recursively inside that if{} block. I hope I'm able to make it a bit clear for you. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: any reason of not using [Future.forEach](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/forEach.html)?

Comment: @pskink Future.forEach on positionStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `playNextPlayer` recursively. In `playNextPlayer`, you are adding a listener to a stream, which later can call `playNextPlayer` when data comes from the stream. I dissect a very similar SO question right [here in this video](https://youtu.be/t8LgA4zcW6M?t=1745).

In your code, the function inside the listen that starts with `(position) async` awaits the playNextPlayer, but that function itself is not awaited by anything outside.

What you want is to start a bunch of async tasks with `.listen`, and then collect their futures and `await` on them.

You can [`.asyncMap()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) the stream so that you get a stream of futures that represent tasks for each item that comes from the stream. Then you can `.tolist()` that stream and give it to `Future.wait()`. That way you can pause execution until all events of your original stream are processed.

Or better, you can process the stream using `await for`, which would avoid many of the headaches that you have here. This way, you let your function continue only after all the events from the stream are processed and the stream is closed.

Comment: Thanks. I processed the stream using 'await for'.